# STS 3.7.2 oracle enterprise pack java prompt

Tags: oracle, weblogic-10.x, spring-tool-suite

I just installed STS 3.7.2. Since my application uses weblogic 10.3.6, i tried installed the oracle enterprise pack (oracle weblogic tools). I finally got around to installing it and now everytime STS starts up, it says "Eclipse is running on JDK 1.7..Oracle enterprise pack requies java 8 and above..". The following screens prompt me to pick jdk 1.8. Once i pick the folder location, STS shuts down. upon starting it up again, i go through the same prompt of picking java 8 installation location. Not sure why STS does not remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modify java home at eclipse.ini

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini